# Jupyter Notebook - very strange bug

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook

I'm a bit startled at the moment and I'm beginning to question my skills.

I have the following program:

```
def readdata(mr_data):

        mr = pd.read_csv(mr_data, sep = ",")
        mrarray = mr.values
        mranswers = {}
        for j in mrarray:
            #print(j) # until here it is correct and the values are different
            if j[0] == 'Subject':
                continue
            if j[0] not in mranswers:
                mranswers[j[0]] = {}

            mranswers[j[0]][j[14]] = j[2]    

        print(mranswers) # here it is the same suddenly, for both datasets
```

This just absolutely does not make any sense. When I call the function with two different files the values in the end (for mranswers) are the same. But when i print j they are actually different, how can this happen and what can I do to avoid that?

Comment: if for both files, `mrarray` is the same, then your dict only retains the values of the last one.

Comment: This code is actually pretty confusing. You're using pandas to read your data but then iterating that data; you might find that using pandas to process the data would be much easier (`mrarray = mr.values` is putting this into python)

Comment: I even changed it now into two seperate functions each with other variable names and the same thing is still happening. This just doesn't make sense at all.

Yeah I'm a little biased to use arrays because I don't like this dataframe thing not very much